# When running powershell in batch file facing error

Tags: powershell

I am doing some testing to run powershell script in cmd. I encountered the error when running the powershell script. Please advise how to rectify it.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "WinVerAct="

For /f "tokens=*" %%W in ('
cscript /Nologo "C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs" /xpr
') Do Set "WinVerAct=!WinVerAct! %%W"
if Not defined WinVerAct ( 
Echo:No response from slmgr.vbs
Exit /B 1
)
Echo Windows Version Activation Status:
Echo:"%WinVerAct:~1%"


ping /n 5 localhost>nul 2>&1

Echo Check Status thru PowerShell
powershell -Command "Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "partialproductkey is 
not null" | ? name -like windows*"
ping /n 5 localhost>nul 2>&1
wmic csproduct
ping /n 5 localhost>nul 2>&1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using two sets of double quotes in the powershell command calling `Get-CimInstance` and obviously as soon as you use the second one it closes that part rather than encompassing the whole expression.

Probably the easiest fix is to just use single quotes for the internal part:

```
powershell -Command "Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter 'partialproductkey is not null' | ? name -like windows*"
```